# What is SQL Server analog for MySql's NEW.some_column in triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is first time I dealing with SQL Server triggers.

Before that I coded nearly same trigger for MySql Server and now trying to recode it for SQL Server. I fixed all things but can't understand what it want now? How else we can access some column of just inserted row like it were possible in MySQL - NEW.some_field?

```
CREATE TRIGGER AntiCloneInsert ON dbo.user_item FOR INSERT AS

DECLARE @acc_id INT;
DECLARE @items_count INT;

IF (NEW.item_type in (select item_type from dbo.forbidden_item_types))
BEGIN
    select @items_count = count(item_type) from dbo.user_item where item_type = NEW.item_type and warehouse = NEW.warehouse
    IF (@items_count > 1)
    BEGIN
        select @acc_id = account_id from dbo.user_data where char_id = NEW.char_id
        update lin2db.dbo.user_account set block_flag2 = 1 where uid = @acc_id
    END
END
```

I trying to create this trigger but getting such errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AntiCloneInsert, Line 6
>   The multi-part identifier "NEW.item_type" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AntiCloneInsert, Line 8
>   The multi-part identifier "NEW.item_type" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AntiCloneInsert, Line 8
>   The multi-part identifier "NEW.warehouse" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AntiCloneInsert, Line 11
>   The multi-part identifier "NEW.char_id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does not have `new` and `old` *records*.  Instead, it has `inserted` and `deleted` *tables*.  This means that the logic can be done using set operations (or loops, if you really prefer).

I think the following is the equivalent logic:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AntiCloneInsert ON dbo.user_item FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN   
    update ua
        set block_flag2 = 1
        from ua join
             dbo.user_data ud
             on ua.uid = ud.account_id join
             inserted i
             on ud.char_id = i.char_id join
             dbo.forbidden_item_types it
             on it.item_type = i.item_type
         where  (select count(it2.item_type)
                 from dbo.user_item it2
                 where it2.item_type = i.item_type and
                       it2.warehouse = i.warehouse
                ) > 1;
END
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you help me one more time? I made this trigger to some guy that needed it and now he told that it needs to be improved with additional insert query after `update`. I don't understand how your trigger works and can't modify it. `insert into dbo.user_punish values ($char_id, 1, 0, NULL, DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE()), NULL, getdate());`

Comment: @Kosmos . . . I don't understand your comment, not do I see how it relates to your query (the table names are different, for instance).  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: I meant that this insert query should be executed together with `update` query from my version of trigger, but guy told me today that trigger bans every player, so something wrong with it's logic. He now trying to recheck rules on which to ban players. So, nothing is needed to do anymore. Thank you.